# Can't display number of items in cart

Tags: html, variables, cart

I'm designing a sample shopping website, and one of the things I want it to be able to do is display the number of items in the shopping cart. I figure the way to do this is to code it so that each time a "purchase" button is clicked to add +1 to the variable displayed in the cart text. The code I have so far is

```
function cart() {
  var cart = document.getElementById("cart").value;
  var cart = cart + 1;
  document.GetElementById("cart").innerHTML=cart
}
```

and the button code is

```
<input type="button" value="Purchase" onclick="cart()" />
```

the display code is

```
  <p id="cart"> 0 </p>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What value is `document.getElementById("cart").value`? (Output using `alert()` or `console.log()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `document.GetElementById()` should follow case-sensitive naming conventions and therefore be called:

```
document.getElementById()
```

You can try this, which includes some safety typecasting:

```
function cart() {
    var itemCount = document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = Number(itemCount) + 1;
}
```

[Check this fiddle for a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2NPAL/2/)

Comment: Check your case - should be `getElementById`, not `GetElementById`

Comment: Thx for pointing it out! Copied the overhauled code block for the demo.